# How do I change the default front-end language in Craft Personal?

Tags: language

Our client wants to have an English back-end, but a German front-end (for now, other languages later). Any idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Only Craft Pro supports multiple locales for a site.  You can see the feature matrix for the different editions here: http://buildwithcraft.com/pricing

Comment: So, if I switch the backend to German, the frontend would be German too?

Comment: The site's primary locale would be German, but I suppose you could just enter the site's content as English?